# Link1 and multiple output files in Gaussian: doable?

Tags: computational-chemistry

I have recently started learning Gaussian in my Computational Chemistry class, and I have recently learned how to use the "Link1" option, in order to run multiple calculations from a single input file.

What I was wondering is: is there an option that allows the creation of multiple output files (one for each "Link1" section), thus allowing an easier interpretation of the results for each calculation?

I couldn't find anything about the problem on the manual or online.

Comment: Can't guarantee because I haven't tried this myself, but I believe what you are looking for is ["punch=all"](http://gaussian.com/punch/). The one issue this might have is I think it only produces a single fort.7 file, so it probably requires an additional option or a separate program to ensure later link1's are sent to different outputs.

Comment: That's indeed an useful option (better than nothing, thank you!)
Apparently, as far as I see, there are no options to change the filename, but this might be a start :)